# Check if value exists in List<List<objects>> in java?

Tags: java, list, collections

I want to check if an objects exists in the `List<List<objects>>` and return the index of `List<<>>` if the object is found.

Eg:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(); 
List<Integer> listOne = new ArrayList<>();
listOne.add(1);
listOne.add(9);
listOfLists.add(listOne);
List<Integer> listTwo = new ArrayList<>();
listTwo.add(5);
listTwo.add(7);
listOfLists.add(listTwo);
```

now I want to find if 9 exists, if so return it's index in the listoflists which is '0'
And should there be any modifications done for it to work with custom objects?

Comment: Iterate through the lists with a `for` loop and check the with `exists()`

Comment: please give an example.

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: In other words: what have you tried, where are you stuck (see [mcve])

Comment: Added example @luk2302

Answer (score 3):

you can use streams to check if an Object exists in your list

```
boolean has = listOfLists.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.contains(Integer.valueOf(9)));
```

and if you find your any match you can get the index

```
List<Integer> list = listOfLists.stream().filter(e -> e.contains(Integer.valueOf(9))).findAny().get();
int index = listOfLists.indexOf(list);
```

in this example the list is generic as `<Integer>` and i'm looking for a certain Integer, namely `Integer.valueOf(9)` but you can adjust for your purpose...

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the list and, if it's contained, return the index

```
for(List<Integer> list : listoflists){
    if(list.contains(9)){
        return listoflists.indexOf(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: That iterates through the list twice: once in your code, and again inside `indexOf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Guava:

```
return Iterables.indexOf(listOfLists, innerList -> innerList.contains(9));
```

This returns the index of the first object found, or -1 if not found.

If your list contains a custom object instead of Integer, the code is exactly the same; it relies on the custom object having a correctly defined `equals()` method.